# Enque function in Java

Tags: java, list, queue

I am currently having an issue implementing a enque function. My Queue class extends a generic class list. below is what i have and i am confused how i would add objects to it. Any help on how i would implements this would gretaly help, thank you.

EDIT:

```
public class List<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    protected Node front=null, rear=null; 
    protected int size = 0;

    public Iterator<T> iterator(boolean fwd) { //fwd true, back false
        return new MyIterator(fwd);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator () {
        return new MyIterator(true);  
    }


    class Node {
        protected Node next,prev; 
        protected T data; 
        public Node(T data){
            next=prev=null;
            this.data=data;
        }
    }

public class Queue<T> extends List<T> {

   public Queue() {
       super();
   }

    public Queue(Queue<T> q) {
        super(q);
    }

    public void enque(T v){
        Node current = rear; 
        rear = new Node(v); 
        rear.data = v; 
        if(!empty()) {
            current.next = rear; 
        }else{
            front = rear; 
        }
        size++;


    }

    public T dequeue(){
        T obj = null; 

        if(!empty()) {
            obj = front.data;
            size--;
       } else {
            System.out.printf("\n\tNothing to dequeue.Queue empty.");
        }
        return obj;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you be clearer what exactly you are trying to do in your code? What is `rear`? Where does it come from? What is `List`? Is it `java.util.List` *interface*?

Comment: @Pshemo List is a class that i created that has the data members protected Node front=null, rear=null;  protected int size = 0; It is a generic class

Comment: That is important information which we can't simply assume. It should be part of the question. How can someone help you use your tools if you don't mention them?

Comment: @Pshemo sorry ill add it